# Сколько в заданный размер ListView влезет item'ов?

Tags: android, java

У меня есть `ListView` статической высоты c 5-ю `item`. Строки в этих `item` могут быть различной длины и в зависимости от этого изменяется высота `item`. Иногда получается так, что в высоту `ListView` все 5 `item` не помещаются и появляется scroll. Необходимо определить сколько в заданный размер `ListView` влезет `item`, а оставшиеся не отображать.

Comment: 3 раза прочитал нече не понял =)

Comment: какой-то и правда непонятный оказался. переформулировал вопрос ))

Comment: все равно не понятно проблемы, может проще использовать тебе 5 TextView. Не понятна вот эта часть "Необходимо определить сколько по размеру влезет items, а оставшиеся не отображать." - остальные и так не будут отображаться.. =)

Comment: разве в конструкторе не видно до какого размера ты его растягиваешь?

Comment: даже если использовать `TextView`. у меня есть определенная область с заданной высотой для отображения этих `TextView`. информация в `TextView` будет подгружаться автоматически и получается, что они могут раздуться по высоте. и вот если все эти 5 `TextView` не влезут в мою ту самую заданную область - часть из них не будет отображаться?

Comment: Если положить 5 TextView-х в нескроллируемый контейнер то те, которые будут вытеснены вниз просто не отобразятся на форме. С другой стороны это чревато тем, что на разных устройствах с разным dpi они могут и отобразиться (частично например).
Может имеет смысл пересмотреть дизайн формы?

Comment: вы правы насчет их отображения/не отображения. необходимо использовать `getMeasuredHeight()` для их определения высоты, получить также высоту заданного `layout` и удалять не поместившиеся `TextView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед добавлением вьюшки в `ListView` надо вызывать `View.measure(int, int)`, фактически он инициирует вызов `onMeasure(int, int)`, перегружая его можно узнать размеры которые будут у контрола при его отображении. Дальше уже принимать решение, добавлять его в список или нет.

Если не вызывать вручную `measure()` то `onMeasure` будет вызван уже после добавления контрола, что в данном случае не подходит.